# Commands for Commander not returning data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-commander

I'm trying to build a node cli to keep an organized planner. I have 'locate' command that goes to the options for commands either 'find' or 'list', but no data is being shown even though the mongoose functions are working correctly. 'todo locate list 12/31/1999' does not return any data back even though there are dates greater than that in my database. Coud someone help me debug this project. The GitHub repository is github.com/tripiod8/todo_cli

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Todo = require('../model/todoSchema');

// Find todo
const findTodoIn = (_tag) => {
   Todo.find({ tag: "Birthday" })
      .then(todo => {
         console.info(todo);
         console.info(`${todo.length} matches`);
         mongoose.disconnect();
      }).catch(err => console.error(err));
};

  // List todo
const listTodoIn = (_date) => {
   Todo.find( { date: { $gte: _date } } )
      .then(todo => {
         console.info(todo);
         console.info(`${todo.length} matches`);
         mongoose.disconnect();
      }).catch(err => console.error(err));
};

module.exports = {
   findTodoIn,
   listTodoIn
};
```

```css
const program = require('commander');
const {findTodoIn, listTodoIn} = require('../controllers/locate');

program
.command('find <tag>')
//.alias('f')
.description('Find a todo')
.action(_tag => findTodoIn(_tag))

 program
 .command('list <_date>')
// .alias('l')
.description('List a todo')
.action(_date => listTodoIn(_date));

program.parse(process.argv);
```

```html
const program = require('commander');

program
.version(pkg.version)
.command('locate', 'Locate a todo')

 program
  .command('add')
  .alias('a')
  .description('Add a todo')
  .action(() => {
      prompt(questions).then((answers) => {
          addTodoIn(answers)
      })
  });


program.parse(process.argv);
```

Comment: You may want to update to using `async` functions, avoiding the `then` mess. Also an argument prefix of `_` means "not used" in most contexts, though you're clearly using them here.

Comment: Have you tried `Todo.find( { date: { $gte: new Date(_date) } } )`?

Comment: I have been running some debugging and my decision is it has nothing to do with the arguments. I have even been trying just a find() and that is not showing data either. It has something to do with  async/await I believe.

let findTodoIn = async () => {
   let updateResult = await Todo.find()
   console.log(`${updateResult} or hello`);
};

Even trying this does not output any data.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database? Does `findTodoIn` work?

Comment: It does work. I can add and remove from the database. I just added a second directory to the cli hierarchy that is not working.

Comment: 1) Is it related to going through Commander? If you call the code directly without going through CLI and Commander does it work?

Comment: 2) Commander allows async action handlers in which case you should call .parseAsync rather than .parse (and handle the returned promise).

Comment: Yea I can query what I'm looking for in Mongo and if I put the 'find' commands in the file with the other commands it works fine. Once I move them to there own file then the commands don't work. I took your suggestion with parseAsync but I have not got it to work for me.

Comment: You may have a problem with dangling promises not keeping the application running. If you add a "sleep" using setTimeout to your main application, do you then see results?

Comment: I used promisify to try the setTimeout and it returned undefined, which is different than it usually not returning anything. I have this on GitHub if you would be interested in taking a look? It's pretty upsetting that I cannot fix this issue. github.com/tripiod8/todo_cli

Comment: I think I see a cause. You are not calling `mongoose.connect` anywhere in your sample code, and looking at your repo, it also does not get called when the `locate` subcommand is run.

Your `todo` command connects to the database through a side-effect when `index.js` is loaded. However, the `locate` subcommand is located in a stand-alone executable and does not load that file or connect to the database.

Comment: You sir were right and found the problem! I added the MongoDB connection to my locate.js and it returned my data successfully! Thank you for helping me and now I should have a better chance of having my todos arranged!